# Facebook Api empty array when trying to get the friendlists

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently developing an ASP.NET SPA application and I am trying to get the list of facebook friends using my application, on the client side with javascript and jquery. The login code works fine, but the returned array is empty, despite the fact I have three friends who loggged in and accepted the default permissions.

Comment: did you ask for user_friends permission from all users too?

Comment: no, because i only need the friends using my app

Comment: You need user_friends permission to see a user's friends in v2.0, even the users who are also app users

Comment: user_friends permission is active

Comment: Was it granted by all of the users you're expecting to see in the response?

Comment: yes, the basic permissions were granted